# Not allocating memory for pointers, is this causing my segmentation fault (core dumped) in C?

Tags: c, debugging, unix, segmentation-fault

I am able to run it on my windows computer in eclipse, but when I try running it on a Unix computer I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". How can I find which line is causing the error? I read this page http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/problems.html which says it could be due to not allocating memory for pointers, but I am getting errors when I try for example `char *users[1000];`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHANGE (10.0/86400.0)       /* 10kg/day */
    /* seconds in a day is 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds */

main() {
    char line[1024];
    char lineC[1024];

    int countToken = 0;
    int lasttime = 0;
    char *tokens;
    char *users;
    int timestamp;
    int duration;
    char userID[1000];
    char lastuser[1000];
    float weight;
    float lastweight;
    float change;
    float changePerTime;

    while (fgets(line,1024,stdin) != NULL) {
        strcpy(lineC, line);
        tokens = strtok(line, " ");
        sscanf(tokens, "%d", &timestamp);   //first token is timestamp
        while(tokens != NULL){
            countToken++;
            tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        int countTemp = countToken;
        users = strtok(lineC, " ");
        while(countTemp > 1){
            if(countTemp == countToken){
                countTemp--;
            }
            else{
                users = strtok(NULL, " .0123456789");
                strcat(userID, users);
                countTemp--;
            }
        }
        users = strtok(NULL, " ");
        sscanf(users, "%f", &weight);

        if (countToken < 1 || timestamp == 0) {
            printf("Invalid time\n");
            continue;
            }
        else if (countToken < 2 || ! (isalpha(userID[0]) || userID[0] == '_') )
            printf("Illegal userID\n");
        else if (countToken < 3 || weight < 30.0 || weight > 300.0)
            printf("Illegal weight\n");
        else if (lasttime >= timestamp)
                printf("Nonmonotonic timestamp\n");
        else {
            duration = timestamp - lasttime;
            change = weight - lastweight;
            changePerTime = change / duration;
            int g = strcmp(lastuser, userID);
            if (lasttime > 0 && (changePerTime < -MAX_CHANGE || changePerTime > MAX_CHANGE) && (g==0))
                printf("Suspiciously large weight change\n");
            else
                printf("OK\n");

            lastweight = weight;
            lasttime = timestamp;
            }
        strcpy(lastuser, userID);
        lasttime = timestamp;
        countToken = 0;
        strcpy(userID,  "");

    }
}
```

Comment: "How can I find which line is causing the error?" scatter some `std::cerr << "I made it to line " << __LINE__ << '\n';` around until you've identified the line....

Comment: No need for that ... compile with -g and run the program via gdb.

Comment: Coredumps might be caused by not allocating memory, but it's something else here: You have to check your calls to `strtok` for `NULL` pointers before using the result. The core dump most likely occurs when you pass `NULL` to `sscanf`. The implementation on Windows seems to guard against this, but Unix is merciless.

Comment: You are miss using NULL pointer

Comment: It is used without having to  initialize the `UserID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it can be hard to start developing for a new platform, but once you understand the basic concepts it is just as easy as any other platform. :)

I would recommend you to do the following:

1. Compile your code with debugging symbols. This will enable you to debug kind of similar to the way you would do it in VS. Using the gcc compiler (and some others) you should use the -g argument to do it.
2. Configure your terminal to generate coredumps. A coredump is an exact copy of the process state at the time where it crashed. Enabling this depends on the terminal you are using (bash, csh, etc) but you can try the following: 'ulimit', 'limits', 'limit'
3. Run gdb. If you used the -g argument to compile, and you have the coredump, you can do 'gdb -c COREDUMP_FILENAME BinaryFilename' It will take you exactly to the line that caused the crash
   2.a Alternately you can run your program from gdb 'gdb BinaryFilename' and step every line until your program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the NULL pointer and before fixing the code, read something more about pointers particular NULL pointer, check this
[Understanding NULL pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_null_pointers.htm)